# wget can't be killed with 'kill -9'

Tags: linux, wget, kill

I've started downloading large file (~30GB) on RedHat Linux using `wget` via SSH. Then I decided to interrupt it, so I pressed `Ctrl+C`. But suddenly it hanged. So I just closed the SSH connection. When I relogged into the system, I've found that this `wget` process isn't dead:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                        
 14834 me   20   0     0    0    0 R 100.0  0.0  22:36.96 wget
```

So I've tried to execute `kill -9 14834`, but it didn't help, despite the process has `R` status. As far as I understand it's normal status for the process to be killed: it's neither zombie, nor uninterruptable. But why it can't be killed then?

P.S. As an another symptom I noticed that I can't `ls` or `du` the folder, where the downloading was initiated: listing hangs and I have to restart the SSH session. Can it be related to the problem above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An unkillable process in state R is either a kernel bug or a hardware fault.

This shouldn't happen, so there is no “legitimate” way to stop it. `kill -9` is as hard as it gets. To find a reliable way of stopping it, you'd need to figure out what the bug is (if it's a software bug) or how the fault affected the system (if it's a hardware fault).

The most fragile part in a PC is the RAM, so do run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/). And make sure that your kernel is up-to-date with the latest available bug fixes.